# Raphael Produces Empty Path

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm learning Raphael.js through this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/ But I got blocked at paths (section 4). Here's my test code:

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Raphael Play</title>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {  
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);  
    var tetronimo = paper.path("M 250 250 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 50 l -50 0 l 0 50 z");  
}
        </script>  
        <style type="text/css">  
            #canvas_container {  
                width: 500px;  
                border: 1px solid #aaa;  
            }  
        </style>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div id="canvas_container"></div>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

For some reason the path comes up empty:

```
<svg height="500" version="1.1" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <desc>Created with RaphaÃ«l 2.1.0</desc>
    <defs/>
    <path style="" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d=""/>
</svg>
```

I've even tried putting a hand crafted path in the d="" param, but no go. Tested in both FF and Chrome, on OSX.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiously, when I paste your code directly into a new .html file on my Desktop, and replace the `<script>` src for the Raphael library with a [public version on CloudFlare](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js), it works fine: I see a Tetris piece.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
```

Maybe there's something wrong with your local copy of Raphael? It's still managing to make an `<svg>` element, so hard to know.

Comment: You know, I'd even saved the commented version directly to disk, so it wouldn't jeopordize the UTF-8. But this did it. So thanks!